# Issue with GSM FTP file upload

Tags: ftp, gsm

We were trying to upload image file to the FTP server using GSM. We are able to upload small .text files. (less than 1KB).

But we are not able to upload files(image file of size 10kb) to the server as when we are trying to connect to server we are getting the following return command

"
AT+FTPPUT=1

OK

+FTPPUT:**1,300**
"

from our knowledge, we can upload file with size of **1300 bytes**.

How we can upload larger files (around 10kb) to the server?

Do we need to split the files? (we tried that but recombining may cause error).

I request your support in this regards. Thanks in advance.....